# ¿Cómo declarar métodos en Python antes de inicializarlos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Trabajo hace mucho con Python,un tema que me incomoda bastante es al momento de usar la Programación Orientada a Objetos, ya que los métodos de las clases son incómodos para mí respecto al orden visual para un programador.

También programo en C++ y veo que se pueden declarar métodos y luego incializarlos con el contenido como este ejemplo:

```cpp
class MiClase{
    public:
        MiClase();
        int metodo_1(int var1, int var2);
        void metodo_2();
};
```

Al hacer esto puedo ver los nombres de los métodos y luego puedo inicializar las funciones:

```cpp
MiClase::MiClase(){
    cout<<"constructor";
}

int MiClase::metodo_1(int var1,int var2){
    cout<<"metodo 1";
}

void MiClase::metodo_2(){
    cout<<"metodo 2";
}
```

De esta forma creo que es más cómodo para un programador. Sin embargo en Python no sé si puedo hacer esto. Simplemente tengo que poner el método completo:

```py
class MiClase:

    def __init__(self):
        print("constructor")
    
    def metodo_1(self,var1,var2):
        print("metodo 1")

    def metodo_2(self):
        print("metodo 2")
```

Esto puede ser un poco incómodo cuando manejo muchos métodos con muchas líneas de código. Mi pregunta es: **¿Cual es la forma más recomendable para poder controlar esto? si es que no la hay ¿Existe alguna manera parecida para mantener el orden visual del código?**

Comment: Si quieres usar un *blueprint* de los métodos que _tendrás_ en tus Clases, podrías usar Clases Abstractas. No es exactamente lo mismo que pides, pero sí una alternativa. Saludos

Comment: python te simplifica las cosas, no las complica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Por qué no sería buena idea

Python no necesita que declares de antemano los métodos de una clase. Es más, en cierto sentido **no puedes** hacerlo porque al tratarse de un lenguaje dínamico, los métodos de una clase pueden variar durante la ejecución del código.

Una clase no es más que otro "objeto" (de un tipo especial) en tiempo de ejecución. Nada te impide asignar a ese "objeto" nuevos atributos y métodos en otras partes del código. Por ejemplo:

```
class Foo:
  def metodo1():
     ...

  def metodo2():
     ...
```

Esta clase tiene dos métodos, pero perfectamente puedes hacer más adelante esto:

```
Foo.metodo3 = lambda self, n: f"Hola {n}"
```

lo que acaba de añadir un tercer método a esa clase, que te se puede llamar a través de un objeto:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.metodo3("John")  # --> Retorna "Hola John"
```

Incluso puedes sustituir por otra cosa lo que hacía cualquiera de los métodos (mecanismo denominado *monkey patching*). Por ejemplo:

```
def otra_funcion(self):
   return "Ahora, algo completamente diferente"

Foo.metodo1 = otra_funcion
```

Todo este dinamismo hace que una "declaración" inicial no sea más que una declaración de "buenas intenciones", pero no hay forma de garantizar que el objeto real en tiempo de ejecucíón no haya sido alterado de alguna forma, por lo que una hipotética declaración previa básicamente sería ignorada por Python si la hubiera incorporado al lenguaje. Su única utilidad es una ayuda visual para el programador. Pero para eso hay cosas mejores, sigue leyendo.

### Por qué no lo necesitas

Precisamente porque todo es dinámico en Python, sus capacidades de **instrospección** son muy poderosas. En tiempo de ejecución puedes obtener todos los métodos y atributos de un objeto haciendo `dir(objeto)`, puedes obtener la documentación de un método haciendo `help(objeto.metodo)`, lo que te dará también el "prototipo" de ese método.

Estas características de introspección son utilizadas por editores modernos como Visual Studio Code o PyCharm, que las usan para darte *en tiempo real* (mientras tecleas) ayuda sobre las funciones, proponerte autocompletado de los nombres de los métodos, y guiarte en los parámetros que hay que pasarles. Si combinas eso con la posibilidad que python tiene de opcionalmente indicar el tipo de los parámetros y del valor retornado, el editor puede incluso chequear si estás invocando correctamente al método y marcarte en rojo si no es así.

No olvides que cada clase y cada método puede llevar documentación en forma de **docstrings** (que es lo que muestra `help()` cuando lo usas en el intérprete interactivo) y estos editores son capaces de extraer esa documentación y ofrecértela como *tooltips* mientras tecleas.

Además estos editores suelen disponer de un "esquema del código" que es una vista similar a la de un arbol de carpetas, que lista los nombres de todas las clases en tu código, y para cada clase lista en un árbol colapsable los nombres de todos sus métodos. Esta vista se puede ordenar alfábéticamente o dejar que siga el mismo orden que tiene en el código. Pichando con el ratón en cualquier lugar de la lista te lleva a la parte correspondiente del código.

El código mismo suele admitir en estos editores la capacidad de **plegar** (folding), es decir, ocultar todo el código que implementa la función dejando solo visible la línea con su declaración. El código así colapsado se parece mucho a la "declaración" por la que tú preguntas, con la ventaja de que basta "descolapsar" cualquiera de los métodos para ver o editar su código.

Aquí tienes una captura de pantalla de VSCode que muestra la clase "plegada" y cómo el editor te sugiere nombres de métodos para autocompletar lo que estás escribiendo. A la izquierda del editor se ve el esquema del fuente, ordenado "por categoría" (primero los métodos, luego los atributos):

[image: VSCode]

### Y si insistes...

Si insistes, nada te impide añadir al incio del fichero un **comentario** explicando qué métodos implementa la clase. El comentario es ignorado por python, igual que sería ignorada una hipotética "declaración previa" que Python decidiera añadir al lenguaje. (E igual que son ignoradas también las declaraciones de tipo en tiempo de ejecución).

Es decir, nada te impide hacer algo como esto:

```
# MiClase implementa los métodos:
#   __init__(self)
#   metodo_1(self, var1, var2)
#   metodo_2(self)

class Miclase:
   # Aqui vendría la implementación real
   ...
```

Pero sinceramente no sé que ganarías con eso. Solo puede servir para introducir errores si más adelante modificas algo en la clase pero olvidas hacerlo en el comentario previo. Es mucho mejor usar un buen editor que haga uso de las capacidades de introspección de Python para ayudarte en tiempo real.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me sirve

Answer (score 3):

C/C++ es un lenguaje al que debes "explicarle" cosas pues es incapaz de entenderlas por si mismo.

Por ejemplo, cuando en modulo1.c necesitas ocupar una función declarada en modulo2.c, tienes que decirle como se llama la función y cuales son sus parámetros.

Esto es porque tras procesar un modulo, C/C++ no conserva ninguna información acerca de cuales era las declaraciones originales. Ergo, tienes que duplicar esa información en otro archivo aparte (el .h correspondient) para poder combinar varios fuentes.

Esto es trabajo extra, innecesario y conducente a errores, cuando cambias la definición de la función en modulo1.c, pero se te olvida cambiar en modulo1.h.

Python, como cualquier otro lenguaje moderno, no necesita esa "ayuda" del programador. Cuando dices

```
from modulo1 import XXX
```

Python por si solo es capaz de cargar el modulo1, buscar XXX, determinar que cosa es (una clase, variable o función) y dejarla disponible para el módulo actual.

Cualquier programa Python es más corto que su equivalente en C/C++, como puedes comprobarlo tú miosmo.

Si estás escribiendo "muchos" métodos con "muchas" líneas, el problema no es el lenguaje. El problema real puede ser que la aplicación es complicada, o más simplemente, el programador.

Comment: Yo no lo llamaría "ayuda" del programador, lo llamaría "especificación", de esa forma se evitan errores y un mejor entendimiento al leer el código. Pero creo que son formas diferentes de entender el código, estuve trabajando con c++ y la constumbre de ver el código de esa forma se me quedó.